# opencsv error with ""\"" in the file

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

i have a problem with reading csv files with openscv.
i use ; as the delimiter.

when i now save csv files, some of them look like this:

```
7. Search by named alleles (please use ""\"" in front of ""*""):
This will return a list of variants for CYP2C9*3.
```

when ""\"" occurs, this destroyes the output of the csvreader.

here is the code i write the csv with:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(folder+"/"+fileNameBase+"_"+numOfFiles+".csv"), ';');
writer.writeAll(data);
writer.close();
```

this is the code i read the csv:

```
csvReader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(currFile.getPath()), ';');
```

does anybody have an idea how to avoid this problem?

best regards,
moritz

Answer (score 1):

Use another [CSVReader constructor](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html#CSVReader%28java.io.Reader,%20char,%20char,%20boolean%29) that allows you to specify how to handle quotes.  Perhaps this one:

```
new CSVReader(new FileReader("foo.csv"), ';', '"', '\\');
```

Similarly, tell the `CSVWriter` what your quote and escape characters are, via its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the "\", it's a reserved character. Try replacing it with "\"